# rosserial and std_msgs [solved]

Tags: ros, std-msgs, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I'm looking for examples rosserial for Arduino and see that they use `std_msgs/String.h` but these files have no ros_lib and in the source package std_msgs String.h also not showed up. From the same header files messages?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11453/rosserial-and-std_msgs-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 471 on 2011-10-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-10-31**:
Ok :) Thanks!

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-10-31**:
You really don't need to go through and mark each question solved -- selecting the appropriate answer with the little checkmark marks it solved.

**Comment by [Daniel Canelhas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1180/daniel-canelhas/) on 2011-10-07**:
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/messages/std_msgs/msg_gen/cpp/include/std_msgs/String.h
do you mean this file? (ros-electric default installation path). or do you mean the message type ($rosmsg show std_msgs/String)? This message is defined in a file called String.msg

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-10-07**:
Which packages are you looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The std_msgs/String.h is generated in ros_lib on running the "rosmake" command as described here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-10-09**:
Thanks a lot!